# How to access firewall configuration in controller?

Tags: symfony, configuration

I'm trying to get the `firewall` information (define in `security.yml`) in one of my controller.

The part I need is the `switch_user` configuration :

```
switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN, parameter: _abagnale }
```

The goal is to create a link in admin section which allows administrators to switch user in one click.

**First test**

I have tried to define this values as parameters.

```
security:
     # ...
     switch_user: { role: %switch_user_role%, parameter: %switch_user_parameter% }

parameters:
   switch_user_role:      ROLE_ADMIN
   switch_user_parameter: _abagnale
```

And now in controller, I can get it with `$this->container->parameters['switch_user_role']`.

This solution is not sufficient, because if I don't want to override default symfony parameters, `switch_user_role` and `switch_user_parameter`will not be defined.

**Second test**

An other way I have tried is to retrieve an object instance that represent the current firewall.

I have discovered I can retrieve firewall name in controller with `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getProviderKey()`

But I'm stuck here because I can't find what I have to do with this value.

So what is the best way to access firewall configuration in controller ?

Comment: Could you elaborate `don't want to override default symfony parameters` - you just want read-only access to `security.switch_user` in a controller **without** using parameters? what's the reason?

Comment: I want to make a link in a template to switch user. I want to reuse this bundle, so I want my link works when developer defines his own switch role/parameter AND when he keeps default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be simple read config file security.yml?

**UPD**:Ok.

I think use DI is simple way for to complete your task.
Sorry, my code for Symfony 2.1. I can't check how it work in 2.3, but i think it don't have global changes for this logic.

All authentication events are processed by some listeners. As Example, `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall` namespace. 
For switch_user event it's  `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SwitchUserListener`. Extend it and be happy.

Code:

Given `security.yml`:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area_2:
        switch_user:
            provider:             ~
            parameter:            _switch_useraaaaa
            role:                 ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
```

I create  my listener.

```
<?php

namespace Nonlux\TestBundle\Symfony;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SwitchUserListener as BaseListener;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AccessDecisionManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SwitchUserListener extends BaseListener
{
    private $usernameParameter;
    private $role;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, UserProviderInterface $provider, UserCheckerInterface $userChecker, $providerKey, AccessDecisionManagerInterface $accessDecisionManager, LoggerInterface $logger = null, $usernameParameter = '_switch_user', $role = 'ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH', EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher = null)
    {
        $this->usernameParameter = $usernameParameter;
        $this->role = $role;
        parent::__construct($securityContext, $provider,$userChecker, $providerKey, $accessDecisionManager, $logger, $usernameParameter, $role, $dispatcher);

    }

    public function getUsernameParameter(){
        return $this->usernameParameter;
    }

    public function getRole(){
        return $this->role;
    }
}
```

I change standart listener with my.

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
...
    - { resource: services.xml }    
...
```

**Important!** By default security authentication listeners have `public = "false"` parameter. But we don't do it and than we can see child listeners in container.
If you don't like to do it. you can create service that can store needed data, fill it from your listener and do your magic.

```
<!-- app/config/services.xml  -->
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">  
    <parameters>
        <parameter key="nonlux.security.authentication.switchuser_listener.class">Nonlux\TestBundle\Symfony\SwitchUserListener</parameter>
    </parameters>
    <services>
        <service id="security.authentication.switchuser_listener" class="%nonlux.security.authentication.switchuser_listener.class%" abstract="true">
            <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="security" />
            <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
            <argument /> <!-- User Provider -->
            <argument type="service" id="security.user_checker" />
            <argument /> <!--  Provider Key -->
            <argument type="service" id="security.access.decision_manager" />
            <argument type="service" id="logger" on-invalid="null" />
            <argument>_switch_user</argument>
            <argument>ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher" on-invalid="null"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Use it in controler ( use service 'security.authentication.switchuser_listener.you_firewall_name')

```
<?php

namespace Nonlux\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

   /**
     * @Route("/switch", name="switch")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function switchAction()
    {
        $name=$this->get("security.authentication.switchuser_listener.secured_area_2")->getUsernameParameter();
        return array('name' => $name);
    }
}
```

See magic in page and be happy.

```
Hello  _switch_useraaaaa
```

Comment: This solution will not be sufficient for two reasons : first, if developer doesn't define a custom value, I will not have access to the default value. Secondly, developer can define security parameters in other file than `security.yml`. So I need to access the "compiled" version (with files concatenation and override) of app configuration

Comment: Could this solution  be help you?